# how to access a rigify armature selector UI?

Tags: rigging, rigify

I generated a rig using rigify but I can't seem to find a UI to select the armature i want. I know other VFX setups usually have a 'paper doll' like image with buttons for each part of the character available to animate. Does rigify provide this UI?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature as far as I know.
Rigify give you a menu that helps hide/unhide parts of your rig. Look in the N-panel (press "n"). In Item you should see Rig Layers.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed Rigify doesn't provide a "picker", but other addons do.

This one is compatible with Rigify (and others): [X-Pose Picker 3.0 - Blender Market](https://www.blendermarket.com/products/x-pose-picker)